# Load records from arbitrary table by primary key passing a list as arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy core functionality without ORM and I need to load records from arbitrary table by primary key passing a list as arguments.

Currently I'm doing it like:

```
records = select([arbitrary_table], list(arbitrary_table.primary_key.columns._all_cols)[0].in_([1, 2, 3]))
```

`arbitrary_table` is passed as parameter and it could be any table with restriction that primary key is integer and not composite, but primary key could have different names.

I have few questions about it:

**Q1:** 
Is there any way to optimize it?
I'm much sure that `list(self.arbitrary_table.primary_key.columns._all_cols)[0]` is NOT the best way to get a primary key column.

**Q2:** 
How to do the same with ORM query?
The example from SA site has `my_user = session.query(User).get(5)` but it takes only one ID as argument and has no override to take a list of IDs.

I will be very thankful for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "primary_key" attribute is an instance of `PrimaryKeyConstraint`, which is iterable in place, so `list(table.primary_key)[0]` is all you need to get at that column.

The example below illustrates two composite-compatible techniques (edit: oh, you said "not composite".  Well it's cool code anyway...use select_by_single_pk()), one requires tuple support (postgresql, maybe mysql), the other one strings out AND/OR, as well as a single PK approach.  Then it shows query.get() which accepts a tuple:

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_, or_, and_

def select_by_composite_pk(table, values):
    "works only in a high-capability database like postgresql"
    return table.select().where(tuple_(*table.primary_key).in_(values))

def select_by_composite_pk_no_tuples(table, values):
    "works in any database"

    return table.select().where(
            or_(
                *[
                    and_(*[col == val for col, val in zip(table.primary_key, val)])
                    for val in values
                ]
            ))

def select_by_single_pk(table, values):
    "works in any database"
    return table.select().where(list(table.primary_key)[0].in_(values))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, MetaData

    eng = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)

    conn = eng.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    m = MetaData()

    # single PK column
    a = Table('a', m, Column('x', Integer, primary_key=True),
                            Column('y', Integer))

    # composite PK column
    b = Table('b', m, Column('x', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('y', Integer, primary_key=True))

    m.create_all(conn)

    conn.execute(a.insert(), [
            {'x': i, 'y': i * 2} for i in xrange(10)
        ])
    conn.execute(b.insert(), [
            {'x': i, 'y': i * 2} for i in xrange(10)
        ])

    print conn.execute(
                select_by_composite_pk(a,
                    [tuple_(3, ), tuple_(5, ), tuple_(9, )])).fetchall()

    print conn.execute(
                select_by_composite_pk(b,
                    [tuple_(3, 6), tuple_(5, 10), tuple_(9, 18)])).fetchall()

    print conn.execute(
                select_by_composite_pk_no_tuples(b,
                    [(3, 6), (5, 10), (9, 18)])).fetchall()

    print conn.execute(
                select_by_single_pk(b, [3, 5, 9])).fetchall()

    # ORM query version
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class MyCompositeClass(Base):
        __table__ = b

    # get accepts a tuple
    print Session(conn).query(MyCompositeClass).get((5, 10))
```

Comment: Great! So I just need to replace `list(arbitrary_table.primary_key.columns._all_cols)[0]` in my code to `list(arbitrary_table.primary_key)[0]`